# Check if user watched entire HTML5 video on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, html, video

i am searching a way to check if user has watched the entire video on iOS device. I have tried 2-3 html5 video frameworks. Now i make tests with Popcorn.js.
I want the user watches the entire video and not skip to the end. I have tried every possible way i could think but nothing works on iOS. I tried the seeked method but it's not be triggered if an iOS user seeks back-and-forth.
In desktop everything works great of-course...

Comment: Have you tried using the `ended` event, or does that also not work on iOS?

Comment: @mpadittech yes i tried. But when a user skips the video and seeks to the end by hand, then the ended event is normally triggered... So i cannot check if the video has truly be watched or the user has skipped it

Comment: Alright, what about the `timeupdate` event? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_timeupdate.asp The description says "The timeupdate event occurs when the playing position of an audio/video has changed." which sounds like exactly what you're looking for, if it works on iOS

Comment: i use timeupdate already. But what about that ? Timeupdate is happening  even if the video is playing normally but is happening even if someone is seeking forward too. The trick here is how to check if someone is seeking forward ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the event also fired when playing normally. Can you post what code you have already in the question?